# Unable to run compiled files - bash: ./a.out: Permission denied. (I've tried chmod)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu, permissions

I've compiled my C source using `cc test.c`, and it did generate `a.out` file.

However when I run it I get this error -

```
bash: ./a.out: Permission denied
```

My source is not in the home directory, it is on different FAT-32 partition, so I've mounted the drive in which the code is using the following command -

```
$ udisks --mount /dev/sda7 --mount-options umask=022
Mounted /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda7 at /media/48E9-FD53
$ cd /media/48E9-FD53/C
```

Then I compile my code using `cc`

I've also tried `gcc`. But still I get the same error.

Then I did - `chmod +x a.out`, still the same problem. Also with(`chmod 755 a.out`) and `chmod u+x a.out`.

I've also tried compiling and executing the program using `sudo`.

I've also tried - `sudo chown sannidhya:sannidhya a.out`.

I've tried every thing that I found after googling, still couldn't get it to work.

How can I run `.out` file (without moving it to home directory)?

**Note** - I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

But a **weird thing** here is, even after running `chmod +x a.out`, on running - `ls -l a.out`, I get-

```
-rw-r--r-- 1
```

also when I check the properties of `a.out`, under **Permissions** tab, when I check `Allow executing file as program`,the tick appears and quickly disappears.

Comment: did you try `sudo chmod +x a.out`

Comment: @MOHAMED I did that...

Comment: This is a question for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @hek2mgl `/dev/sda7 on /media/48E9-FD53 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)`

Comment: From experience, it's a bad idea to use gcc on a win remote partition. It causes a lot of problems. I would recommend : using a source repository (github ?) if backup is the problem. if you control the system, you can also reverse the situation (widows accessing linux folder via a samba share)

Comment: @Offirmo It is not a remote partition. It exists on my drive. But it is FAT32.

Comment: So you have no permissions, no symlinks... Not the best place to do some unix hacking...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems that you've mounted the partition with with no-exec flag set. You'll have to remount the partition:

```
sudo mount -o remount -o exec /dev/sda7
```

Comment: can you add the output of `mount | grep sda7` ?

Comment: `/dev/sda7 on /media/48E9-FD53 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,fl‌​ush,uhelper=udisks)`

Comment: I'm having the same mount options, and the same filesystem (vfat). And it works... Hmm

Comment: Do I need chmod even after that?

Comment: I would *for testing* do anything as root. And then check if `ls` if the executable bit is set. Then try to run ./a.out

Comment: Hehe! :) fine!.. Although in this case it seems to be an usb stick, you should have this in mind any time you mount a cdrom.

Comment: All right, so this command will unmount if the drive was already mounted and the mount it again, right? How do mount it if it wasn't mounted before? Is this alright - `sudo mount -o exec /dev/sda7`. BTW: what is the purpose of the `-o` parameter?

Comment: yes, then just drop the `-o remount` and use your regular mount command and add `-o exec` . Btw, for usb sticks this should work *out of the box* with ubuntu 12.04 as I'm using it too. It looks like that you have enabled this no-exec monting to prevent form malware etc on usb sticks..

Comment: When I mount it freshly using `sudo mount -o exec /dev/sda7`, I get this error - `mount: can't find /dev/sda7 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`.

Comment: you missed the path where it should be mounted. Call it like: `mount OPTIONS DEVICE TARGET_PATH`

Comment: When I compile, I get this - `/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file a.out: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`. However, there is no problem while running the file. Strange...

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess you are doing all of this on an **NTFS/FAT partition** that you probably share with windows. chmod permissions **do not work** on them.

You should move it to an `ext4` (or equivalent linux) partition, and then perform permission changes.

---

Else, for an NTFS/FAT partition, you set permissions [**for the entire partition**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition), at the time of mounting.
For example,

```
sudo umount /mnt/my_partition
sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0000,dmask=0000 /dev/sda7 /mnt/my_partition
```

This would give you `777` on all directories and files (eeeek!), but once set, you can't modify them till you remount.

Comment: @Sann Same logic. You can only apply permissions to the entire partition when you mount, if it isn't a linux native partition. Move it to a linux partition for `chmod` to work.

Comment: What do I pass in for `mount point` parameter? I am getting this error - `mount: mount point /media/48E9-FD53 does not exist`

Comment: Did you manage to mount it successfully? `mount | grep sda7` should now reflect the new `dmask` and `fmask` set. Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it using `fstab`

```
cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 1
D:      /mnt/d  drvfs   defaults,user,metadata,exec     0       0
```