# Ubuntu 13.10 , Golang build and run, the terminal display error bash: ./filename : Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, build, go

I am trying to run Go's executable file after using command `go build` instead of typing `go run filename.go`.

I typed `go build` in the directory where the Golang source file resides. After the executable file had been created, I typed `./filename` to run it. Then the terminal displayed a line :

```
bash : ./filename : Permission denied
```

I had tried to change the permission of the filename by typing :

```
chmod u+x filename
```

But this action doesn't give any effects. The permission denied error still occurs whenever I type `./filename`.

Is there another way to build a Golang applications from source code, and then run it from executable file?

All things done well if I do this task in Windows command prompt, after typing `go build`, the `filename.exe` is created and there is no any problem when I run it by typing `./filename.exe`.

Comment: Could you provide a `ls -lah` listing where you binary is located, so we can be sure that's not the permissions problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to run compiled files - bash: ./a.out: Permission denied. (I've tried chmod)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087752/unable-to-run-compiled-files-bash-a-out-permission-denied-ive-tried-chm)

Comment: In relation to @Kavu's comment, is your Go workspace on a native Linux file system (e.g. ext4), or are you trying to do this from a mounted Windows filesystem?

Comment: My source is on NTFS partition.

/dev/sda6 on /media/keworld/PROGRAMMING type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NTFS and FAT have different permission models than Unix. This especially means that there is no executable flag on such  a file system. Calling `chmod a+x FILE` is a no-op. Linux emulates classical Unix permissions on NTFS file systems by setting a mask for each file that contains the would-be permissions.

To fix these problemss, either move executables to a different file system or change the mount flags to use a permission mask that enables the executable-flag (for all files).

Comment: I really don't know why and how this problem can be solved easily when I use UDisk to set the /dev/sda6 to be automounted at system start up. Just go to "Edit Mount Options" then turn on "Automatic Mount Options", press OK.

Comment: The default_permissions don't contain execute permissions. The auto mounter uses different permission I guess.

Comment: Maybe you are right.Automatic Mount options don't contain default_permissions in setting. It just contain "nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show". 
Thank for you answer.